# How do I fix the Bootstrap Accordion Arrow direction?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I am using Bootstrap 5.1 with the [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/) feature. However, when the page loads the Chevron is upside down and only rights itself after clicking on it a couple of times.

Here is the code:

```
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h4 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        Current Courses
                </button>
                </h4>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
  <div class="accordion-body">
                    {current_courses}
                        <p class="course"><a class="course-link" href="{current_courses:link_to_course}">{current_courses:title}</a> 
                        {current_courses:hours} CPE Hours {current_courses:course_date}</p>
                    {/current_courses}
                </div><!-- /. accordion-body -->
            </div><!-- /.collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.accordion-item -->
```

The Accordion works correctly but the chevron first appears like this:

[image: Chevron upside down]

Here is the css for the accordion:

```
.accordion-button::after {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23A81912'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
        }
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23A81912'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
        }
```

Any help in getting the chevron turn around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure that you use a unique id for both `.accordion-button` and `.accordion-collapse`.

---

If it is collapsed by default, add the `.collapsed` on the `.accordion-button`  and set `aria-expended` to `true`.

```css
.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23A81912'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23A81912'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h4 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         Current Courses
     </button>
    </h4>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        {current_courses}
        <p class="course"><a class="course-link" href="{current_courses:link_to_course}">{current_courses:title}</a> {current_courses:hours} CPE Hours {current_courses:course_date}</p>
        {/current_courses}
      </div>
      <!-- /. accordion-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.accordion-item -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this! Problem solved.